# How can I bind two user controls together?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm stuck in a problem right now and I think I'm lost.
My project (C# WPF MVVM) consists of the following components (no framework):

- ShellView (Window)
- ShellViewModel
- MainView (Usercontrol) <-- 2 Textboxes for Userinputs (int values)
- MainViewModel <-- Added both integer and put the result in a int-property
- ResultDisplay (UserControl) <-- One Label witch should display the result

Both user controls are loaded into the shell view and displayed there.

How can I now connect the ResultDisply with the property of the MainView.

I've tried setting the Data.Context of the DisplayView to the MainViewModel and binding its label to the MainViewModel's property (ResultOutput).
When setting the autoproperty (1234) it works and 1234 is displayed. But everything that changes during runtime is no longer displayed.
I've already thought about DependensyProperty, but I can't implement it.

MainViewModel:
`

```
private string resultOutput = "1234";

        public string ResultOutput
        {
            get { return resultOutput; }
            set 
            { 
                resultOutput = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }


        private void AddTwoNumbers()
        {
            int result = Num1 + num2;
            ResultOutput = result.ToString();
        }
```

`DisplayView:`

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="ResultTB"
               Content="{Binding ResultOutput}"
                   Background="#333"
                   Foreground="LightGray"
                   FontSize="40"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                   Padding="8,0,0,5" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`
I hope someone can help me out of the darkness. :-)

Comment: Generally you don't use VMs for controls - use _dependency properties_ instead.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Result");` - shouldn't this be `OnPropertyChanged("ResultOutput");`?

Comment: Hey Klaus, yes you are right. I had created the small test project for tests and for the question here in the forum and of course tried out a lot. I didn't even notice that I didn't change the string at all.
I've now changed it to nameof(ResultOutput) and everything works.
Thank you Klaus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xaml
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This is wrong approach, because you create **new instance** of MainViewModel.

I've had the same problem, solution (without `DependencyProperty`) that works for me is to place your `UserControl` inside container (for example StackPanel) and bind DataContext of this container.

```cs
class ShellViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Window x:Class="ShellView" ...>
     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}">
         <MainView/>
         <ResultDisplay/>
     </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So now `MainView` and `ResultDisplay` have the same `ViewModel` object

Comment: Thanks for the quick help George.
I've tried to implement your solution, but I still fail because of a probably very stupid error.
Could you please take a look?